# For the system $u_t+Au_x+Bu_y=0$ to be hyperbolic, what conditions must $A$ and $B$ satisfy in the $t$ direction?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

So I got a few questions, I came across this problem in a PDE text.

Consider this PDE, $u_t+Au_x+Bu_y=0$, what condition must $A$ and $B$ satisfy for the system to be hyperbolic in the $t$ direction? What are some simple cases? If $A$ and $B$ are diagonal, what would be the condition that results in the system being strictly hyperbolic?

I'm seeking conceptual understanding, so with that said, any hints are welcome or knowledgeable input that can explain this

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$ constants or functions ? Also in your question the definition of "hyperbolic" for a first order PDE is missing. The definition of "in the $t$ direction" as well.

Comment: ok, I'll update in a bit

Comment: @JJacquelin so $A$ and $B$ are matrices, I'll update the question with definition of elliptic and strictly hyperbolic from the book. I'm still not sure what they mean by t direction

Comment: See Definition 9.2.2 from John Strikwerda - Finite Difference Schemes and Partial Differential Equations (2nd Edition). The definition of hyperbolicity is related to the well-posedness of the PDE, which is explained a little more in the book itself.